# "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" vs "Unexpected token }"

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

I have jquery code that dynamically writes HTML. I was originally getting a "missing ) after argument list" error with the following code to my index.html file:

```
             $("#ride").append('<div class= "style"><img src = "' 
                 + snapshot.val().id 
                 + '" style="width:68px;height:68px;"/><p>' 
                 + snapshot.val().user 
                 + '</p><ul class = "styling"><li>'  
                 + snapshot.val().when 
                 + ' '
                 + snapshot.val().from 
                 + ' - ' 
                 + snapshot.val().to 
                 + '</li><li>' 
                 + snapshot.val().comments 
                 + '</li><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick = "initMessenger(' 
                 + snapshot.val().user 
                 + ' , '
                 + snapshot.val().reference 
                 + ')">join this ride</button></ul></div>');
```

After reading various posts, I thought that it might be because I'm passing in strings to the function without quotes around them? So I have done:

```
             $("#ride").append('<div class= "style"><img src = "' 
                 + snapshot.val().id 
                 + '" style="width:68px;height:68px;"/><p>' 
                 + snapshot.val().user 
                 + '</p><ul class = "styling"><li>'  
                 + snapshot.val().when 
                 + ' '
                 + snapshot.val().from 
                 + ' - ' 
                 + snapshot.val().to 
                 + '</li><li>' 
                 + snapshot.val().comments 
                 + '</li><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick = "initMessenger("' 
                 + snapshot.val().user 
                 + '" , "'
                 + snapshot.val().reference 
                 + '")">join this ride</button></ul></div>');
         });
```

However, now I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }". More interestingly, it seems to give this error with a single (seemingly) random line each time. So far its claimed these lines have respectively caused the exception

`<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<html>`

in my index.html file. Even more strangely, the javascript that I'm struggling with is not housed in this js file.

full postRides.js:

```
function loadRides(direction, airport) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, function(errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
    var x = 0;
    ref.child(direction + '/' + airport).once("value", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(snapshot) {


            $("#ride").append('<div class= "style"><img src = "' +
                snapshot.val().id +
                '" style="width:68px;height:68px;"/><p>' +
                snapshot.val().user +
                '</p><ul class = "styling"><li>' +
                snapshot.val().when +
                ' ' +
                snapshot.val().from +
                ' - ' +
                snapshot.val().to +
                '</li><li>' +
                snapshot.val().comments +
                '</li><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick = "initMessenger(\"' +
                snapshot.val().user +
                '" , "' +
                snapshot.val().reference +
                '\")">join this ride</button></ul></div>');


        });


    });

}

function initMessenger(name, reference) {
    console.log('initMessenger called with this reference: ' + reference);
    if (window.currentUser) {
        console.log('you are signed in');
        document.getElementById('convoHeader').innerHTML = name;
        document.getElementById('messages-card').style.display = "";
        window.friendlyChat = new FriendlyChat(reference);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block';
        console.log('you are not signed in');
    }

}
```

index.html:

```
<head>
    <title>Columbia Ride Share</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="messenger.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="post-ride.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="top">
        </div>
        <h1 class="page-title">Columbia Ride Share</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-link" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">CREATE A RIDE</button></a>
                </li>
                <div id="id02" class="modal">
                    <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
                        <div class="imgcontainer">
                            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loginMsg">
                            <p>Where are you headed?
                                <p>
                                    <a href="create-a-ride-to-airport.html">I need a ride to the airport</a>
                                    <a href="create-a-ride-from-airport.html">I need a ride to campus</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <li class="login">
                    <button id="quickstart-sign-in" "style="width:auto; ">LOGIN</button></li>
             <div id="id01 " class="modal ">
                 <form class="modal-content animate " action="action_page.php ">
                     <div class="imgcontainer ">
                         <span onclick="document.getElementById( 'id01').style.display='none' " class="close " title="Close Modal ">&times;</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="loginMsg ">
                         <p>hi there!</p>
                         <p>log in to post and join on columbia ride share</p>
                     </div>
                     <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook ">connect with facebook</button>
                     <button onclick = "googleSignin() " class="loginBtn loginBtn--google ">connect with google</button>
                  </form>
               </div>

           </ul>
     </nav>
</header>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<div id= "ride "></div> 


 <div id="messages-card-container " class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid ">

  <!-- Messages container -->
  <div id="messages-card " style="display:none; " class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop ">
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600 ">

      <div id="convoHeader ">HEADER</div>
  <div class="wrapBox ">
      <div id="messages ">
        <span id="message-filler "></span>
      </div>
      <form id="message-form " action="# ">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label ">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input " type="text " id="message " placeholder="Type a message... ">
        </div>
      </form>
      <form id="image-form " action="# ">
        <input id="mediaCapture " type="file " accept="image/*,capture=camera ">
        <button id="submitImage " title="Add an image " class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--amber-400 mdl-color-text--white ">
        </button>
      </form>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="must-signin-snackbar " class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar ">
    <div class="mdl-snackbar__text "></div>
    <button class="mdl-snackbar__action " type="button "></button>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase.js "></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-app.js "></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-auth.js "></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-database.js "></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-messaging.js "></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-storage.js "></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAIY9XOb5QVDTxJKxtvSZRiyqgpGasHF3M ",
    authDomain: "columbia-ride-share.firebaseapp.com ",
    databaseURL: "https://columbia-ride-share.firebaseio.com ",
    storageBucket: "columbia-ride-share.appspot.com ",
    messagingSenderId: "1058399238109 "
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  this.auth = firebase.auth();
  this.database = firebase.database();
  this.storage = firebase.storage();
  this.messaging = firebase.messaging();
</script>

<script src="messenger.js " type="text/javascript "></script>
<script src="postRides.js " type="text/javascript "></script>
<script>loadRides("TOairport ", "JFK ");</script>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none ";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

window.onclick= function(event){

    if(event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none ";
    }
}
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js " integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin=" anonymous "></script>
<script src="app.js " type="text/javascript "></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      initApp();
    };
</script>

<script>
    $('#convoHeader').click(function(){
    if($('.wrapBox').is(":visible ")){
        $('.wrapBox').hide();
    $('#messages-card-container').addClass('hide_wrapBox');
    console.log('you get here');
    }else{
        $('.wrapBox').show();
    $('#messages-card-container').removeClass('hide_wrapBox');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: change this "initMessenger(" to "initMessenger(\"  and '")" to '\")"

Comment: "*I have jquery code that dynamically writes HTML.*" - Don't. Write jQuery code that builds a DOM *structure*. And **never** dynamically write JavaScript code, as you do for your click handler - use a closure instead.

Comment: Whoa. Please use some [proper (auto)indentation](http://jsbeautifier.org/) on that code.

Comment: Are you getting the error after you click the button, or on page load?

Comment: after I click the button

Comment: Then you should check your "initMessenger" function, which we can't see.

Comment: The `  });` at the very end of your code snippet is out of place here. It indicates that you’re closing off another function with an object or function it it, and that’s probably not right. What text editor are you using? If it has syntax highlighting, it will be a tremendous help.

Comment: @Manngo, I've just been editing in terminal actually

Comment: Yes, the error is not there, maybe at inner levels. You can use the Chrome dev tools right? copy the codes around the line which gives this exception.

Comment: @Elizabeth Which editor? I use __Joe__ which includes syntax highlighting, but there are others. In any case, what about the trailing characters?

Comment: @Manngo, you're right. I took them out of the code snippet, because you couldn't tell that they actually belong to the preceeding "data.forEach(function(snapshot) { "

Comment: @TahaPaksu, strangely it seems to just pick a random line in the index.html and claims it causes the exception. I can list in my post the ones I've seen so far

Comment: Ok then, use a code formatter and look where the code gets out of order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax error (or an escape nightmare one might say). here is the answer:

```
$("#ride").append(`
<div class="style">
    <img src="${snapshot.val().id}" style="width:68px;height:68px;"/>
    <p>${snapshot.val().user}</p>
    <ul class="styling">
    <li>${snapshot.val().when} ${snapshot.val().from} - ${snapshot.val().to}</li>
    <li>snapshot.val().comments</li>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="initMessenger('${snapshot.val().user}','${snapshot.val().reference}')">join this ride</button>
    </ul>
</div>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue. Try this:

```
 $("#ride").append('<div class= "style"><img src = "' 
                 + snapshot.val().id 
                 + '" style="width:68px;height:68px;"/><p>' 
                 + snapshot.val().user 
                 + '</p><ul class = "styling"><li>'  
                 + snapshot.val().when 
                 + ' '
                 + snapshot.val().from 
                 + ' - ' 
                 + snapshot.val().to 
                 + '</li><li>' 
                 + snapshot.val().comments 
                 + '</li><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick = "initMessenger(\"' 
                 + snapshot.val().user 
                 + '" , "'
                 + snapshot.val().reference 
                 + '\")">join this ride</button></ul></div>');
```

Comment: still get “Unexpected token }” :/

Comment: @Elizabeth, Looks like issue with some other code snippet. Can you share whole code.

Comment: it looks like this code is producing some pretty weird HTML (specifically the call to init messenger): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqMZob

Comment: @Matt, What is `data` attribute in codepen which you shared?

Answer (score 0):

if you split string to multiline you need to use '/' on each line then

```
  $("#ride").append('<div class= "style"><img src = "' /
             + snapshot.val().id /
             + '" style="width:68px;height:68px;"/><p>' /
             + snapshot.val().user /
             + '</p><ul class = "styling"><li>'  /
             + snapshot.val().when /
             + ' '/
             + snapshot.val().from /
             + ' - ' /
             + snapshot.val().to /
             + '</li><li>' /
             + snapshot.val().comments /
             + '</li><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick = "initMessenger(\"' /
             + snapshot.val().user /
             + '" , "'/
             + snapshot.val().reference /
             + '\")">join this ride</button></ul></div>');
```

Comment: hmm when I did this, then it wouldn't render the html on the page at all

Comment: Incorrect, you mix this with string literal continuation, also should be backslashes here.

Comment: @Elizabeth Please ignore this answer. (a) concatenating strings as you have done does _not_ require additional slashes; (b) only if you try to line break up a string literal (which is _not_ the case), then you should use the __backslash__ (\\).